# Some pages are not numbered for me - let\clearpage\relax

Tags: latex

I used \let\clearpage\relax to keep two chapters on one page and this is causing the page number on proceeding page not to be displayed.

Is there a way I can undo the command in the document and still keep two chapters one page?

More detail provided.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=-2cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{setspace}
\makeatletter

% addition for not showing 'Chapter 1'
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \thechapter\nobreakspace
    \fi
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}


\@ifundefined{chapter}%
   {}%
     {\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
            \ifthenelse{\value{chapter} < 1}%
                {\markboth{#1}{}}%
                {\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
        }}


\addtolength{\headheight}{\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %% thin line under header
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %% no line under header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}                            %% Clear all fields.
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\thepage}
%\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\sffamily\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily\thepage} % except the center
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can easily reproduce your problem and try to help you. Also will be nice to provide latex version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a combination of two factors:

- you document uses different page styles for chapter pages and normal pages. On chapter pages, the page number had been at the bottom centre, on normal pages there was a header with the chapter title and the page number
- you were using the `geometry` package with a large negative top margin. This pushed the header of normal pages off the page and you did no longer see the page number on them.

Proposed solution:

- use a reasonable values for the page geometry, e.g. `\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}`

  This also has the advantage, that one can remove most of the hard codes `\vspace`s in your figures and tables
- if you'd like to remove the header and move the page number to the bottom centre on all normal pages, the following definitions can be used:

  ```
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily\thepage} % except the center
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  ```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work for me. I'm using document style report. I'm using chapters for each section in my report instead of e.g. section, as they provide preferred numbering style by my university.

Comment: @MichałWietlicki Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question? If I replace `book` by `report` in my above example, it still works fine.

Comment: @MichałWietlicki The problem is `top=-2cm` in the geometry settings. This pushes the header with the page numbers off the page. If I remove this, I see the page numbers again.

Comment: When I remove top or and bottom, same problem still prevails for me.

Comment: @MichałWietlicki That's strange. Can you make a small, but compilable example that reproduces the problem? If I add the preamble you show in your question to the document from my answer, it works fine.

Comment: Do you use overleaf? If so, I could create like a shared document with you, if you give me your overleaf email. It could be something to do with text and figures I think. If I remove all text and tables, it works fine.

Comment: Or if you give your email address, I can email you entire code text and figures, including.

Comment: @MichałWietlicki Sorry, I don't have an email for public distribution, but if you use the `share` button on the top right of overleaf and past the link here, I should be able to see the code.

Comment: As you see the pages 2 and 4 are unnumbered

Comment: @MichałWietlicki Thanks! I'll have a look.

Comment: @MichałWietlicki Please look now. I fixed an error about missing math mode in a table and removed the -2cm top margin. Now the header including the page number is visible. If you don't want a header and have the page number at the bottom of the page, this can be adjusted

Comment: Thank you very much @Samcarter ! Just copy what you have added to my code in to your post on this site and I will accept it. But please give me sometime as I will be away for few hours from computer now.

Comment: @MichałWietlicki I tried to summarise the changes in my answer. Off-topic: you might want to have a look into the `siunitx` package. This allows to easily typset units correctly, e.g. upright and with half a space between value and unit.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything once again!